# Integration by parts - order of $u$ and $v$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have the following integral to find:

$$\int 12x^2(3+2x)^5 dx$$

Now, I am aware of the integration by parts property -

$$\int \ u \frac{dv}{dx} = uv - \int v\frac{du}{dx}$$

Now, my question is the following -

When I make $u = 12x^2$, I find a different answer to when I make $u = (3+2x)^5$.

In integration by parts, can I make the value of $u$ whatever I want?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you choose for $u$, it should end up being the same answer. Having said that, the choice of $u$ and $v$ in general can be chosen in such a way to make the calculation easier.

Comment: In this case (if you must use integration by parts) then I'd recommend using $u=12x^2$, since this allows the new integral to have a lower power of $x$ outside the bracket. You will likely need to apply the integration by parts twice.

Comment: You have to choose, the difference is that depending on what you choose for $u$ to be it's going to be the number of iterations you're going to have to do in order to solve the integral. This number is determined by the exponent of the function you name $u$, so $u = 12x^2$ is the better choice, because you'll only need to do it twice instead of five times if you choose $u = (2x + 3)^5$, in this case $dv = (2x+3)^5 dx$, so in order to get $v$ you have to integrate $dv$.

Answer (score 2):

For solving integrals like this, with two small power and large power, we must exchange parenthesis by substitution. For instance I want to solve the integral
$$I=\int 12x^2(3+2x)^{50} dx$$
which second has power $50$. With substitution $3+2x=u$ and $2dx=du$, the integral will simplify to
$$I=\int 12\left(\frac{u-3}{2}\right)^2u^{50} \dfrac{du}{2}= \dfrac32\int(u^2-6u+9)u^{50}du=\dfrac32\int(u^{52}-6u^{51}+9u^{50})du$$
I think this method may help in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to an integration may appear different without actually being different.  For example:

$\int(x+2)^3\,dx$ by substitution, $\frac{1}{4}(x+2)^4 + C$.

By expanding first,

$\int(x+2)^3\,dx = \int(x^3+6x^2+12x+8)\,dx = \frac{x^4}{4}+2x^3 + 6x^2+8x+C$

These answers appear different..  But if you expand the first, you will see that they differ by only a constant.  So the values of $C$ in the two cases are different.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer already given (namely that that it does not matter which function you pick as "$ u $", as long as it's differentiable), may I suggest to make the substitution $ u = 3 + 2x $. Then
\begin{align*}
\int 12x^2(3+2x)^5 \: \mathrm{d}x &= \int 12 \left( \frac{u-3}{2} \right)^2 u^5 \: \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2} \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \int \left( u^7 - 6u^6 + 9u^5 \right) \: \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \int u^7 \: \mathrm{d}u - 9 \int u^6 \: \mathrm{d}u + \frac{27}{2} \int u^5 \: \mathrm{d}u ,
\end{align*}
which is easy to evaluate. Then resubstitute to obtain an answer in $ x $. Beware, though, of adjusting the limits of integration when changing variables.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter to the final result what function you pick as $u$. You just need to determine what substitution will let you to get the result faster.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the same answer which ever way you do it, but setting $u=(3+2x)^5$ is going to take a long time.

But an easier method is just a direct substitution $u=3+2x$, much quicker than integration by parts.